# Time travel book where a father loses his children by changing his past

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I’m trying to locate a book with only a minimum of memory of the book, other than I really enjoyed it!

It’s time travel, and the premise is that a man (a father/husband) is given the chance to travel back to a younger version of himself. In doing so, he obviously changes his future, not realising his children will no longer exist. The changes in his actions mean they weren’t born. Even if he has children in his new future, they won’t be the same ones he left behind.

He grieves, helped by a woman he meets at a self-help group whose child died (through natural causes, not lost to time travel).

Sorry, I know that’s really basic, but I'm hoping someone has read it. 
I read it on Kindle but can no longer find it in my library.

Comment: The consequence that the children will no longer exist is a plot point in Ken Grimwood's *Replay*, but I don't think the rest is a match.

Comment: When did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art or any names from the story?

Comment: @DavidW "It was on kindle and would have been around 6 years ago maybe. I lose track of time so by 6 years it could be 15 or 3! Being as it was in kindle I have scoured my library and find nothing so I wonder if it was deleted and no longer available?" (From an answer on its way to deletion. Looks like OP was locked out of their account and couldn't edit.)

Comment: Another story on the same theme (not the one you're looking for) is Lord Dunsany's short story "Lost" in his collection *The Fourth Book of Jorkens*, about a man who went back in time to undo some mistakes in his past, and so lost his home, his wife, his stamp collection, everything he cared about.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it was a book?

The description is very similar to the film [About Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_Time_(2013_film)) (2013)

Edit - actually, there is [a novelization of the movie.](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/25796240)  Maybe you read that?

> On his 21st birthday, Tim learns from his father that the men of his family have the ability to travel back in time to moments they have lived before.
> ...
> he is in love with Mary. He proposes; they marry and have a daughter, Posy.
> ...
> Kit Kat's relationship and employment struggles lead her to drunkenly crash her car on Posy's first birthday. As Kit Kat recovers, Tim decides to intervene in her life: he prevents the crash and takes Kit Kat back in time to avert her unhappy relationship with Jimmy. They manage to return to the present, where Tim finds Posy has never been born and he has a son instead.

And note, the time travel is in the form of his mind traveling back into his younger body.

Comment: Is it the short story Needle in A timestack. I read it in a collection of the same name. The author is Robert Silverberg.